# using window as a prototype returns seemingly wrong values in javascript

Tags: javascript

you'd expect this code to return "123", but instead it returns the window object

```
function W() {
    this.window = "123";
}

W.prototype = window;

(new W()).window; // window object, not "123"
```

please check followup question ([window as prototype makes setTimeout behave oddly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37051606/window-as-prototype-makes-settimeout-behave-oddly))

Comment: Why would you do this? - Also, `window.window` is `window`, and as far as I know, it is immutable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it was already pointed out `window.window` is immutable, but you can define own `window` property in `W()` constructor function.

```js
function W() {
  Object.defineProperty(this, 'window', {
    configurable: true,
    enumerable: true,
    writable: true,
    value: '123'
  });
}

W.prototype = window;
document.write(new W().window); //123
```

Comment: so as I understand it immutability is also inherited moo?

Comment: please check followup question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37051606/window-as-prototype-makes-settimeout-behave-oddly

Answer (score 4):

The `window` property on a global `window` object refers to itself, and it is immutable.

Therefore, the constructor `W` cannot set the property to `123`.

```
window.window; // returns window object

window.window = "123";

window.window; // still returns window object
```

If you try to set a non-immutable property in your `W` constructor, you will see that it works correctly.

```
function W() {
    this.notWindow = "123";
}

W.prototype = window;

(new W()).notWindow; // returns "123"
```

This is nothing to do with the prototype, and is instead to do with trying to set immutable properties. Very interesting question, though!

Comment: Exactly... even if one were to create an object, which has the window as it's prototype.

Comment: But, why is `this` the window object when the function is called with `new`?

Comment: @nnnnnn: Because the prototype is `window`. If you look in Chrome and inspect `new W()`, you will see that `notWindow` is a property of `W`, where as all other properties are inherited from its prototype (window). http://i.imgur.com/wmNiPLe.png

Comment: It doesnt make sense, because you have propery `this.window` and it returns `123` until you re-assign `W.prototype` to `window`

Comment: I guess it's, because you can't have the prototype be the window object and override the window properties.

Comment: @The: That is because until you re-assign `W.prototype` to `window`, the `window` property is not immutable.

Comment: @JamesMonger why assigning prototype affect object property?

Comment: OK time to clarify it. `window` refers to the global object which is immutable. `window` has a pointer called `window` that points to itself, allowing you to call `window.window...` ad infinitum to refer to the same object. The error in OP's code is `(new W())` which is an object of type `W`, NOT `Window` (the interface which `window` implements). If he instantiates an object of type `Window`, the `window` property is not immutable.

Comment: @user6292850 also doesnt make sense, without assigning `prototype` to `window` code works well, why assigning `window` as a `prototype` affects object property (`this.window`)?

Comment: @nnnnnn It isn't. `this` refers to `W`, not the `window` object.

Comment: @Tresdin - I was wrong before, but I get it now. `this` does *not* refer to `W`, but `this instanceof W` is `true`.

Answer (score 2):

It's not about the `window` property, it's about immutability.

When you assign values to an immutable property, they will be ignored. This example will reintroduce the issue with another immutable property.

```js
function W() {
  this.immutableProperty = 0;
}

W.prototype = Object.create({},{
  immutableProperty: {
    value: 1
  }
});
alert(new W().immutableProperty); //1
```

Comment: but in my example the W does not have an immutable property window. W's prototype (window) does. so it seems immutability of properties is also inherited.

Answer (score -1):

The other answer is not strictly correct. The problem with your code is that the window interface is [`Window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/window) (notice the capital W). `Window.window` refers to the `window` object, allowing your code to work properly.

```
function W() {
    this.window = "123";
}

W.prototype = Window;

(new W()).window; // 123
```

Comment: The answer by @James Monger is 100% correct, while yours is **incorrect**. `Window` is not what you think, and thus W instance is simply not going to inherit a thing from window, OP's intention. It has to be `window`, not `Window`.

Comment: @dfsq `W.prototype = window;` is a syntax error, `W.prototype = Window;` is not. OP's question is horribly underspecified. If I take it literally that he wants an output of "123", this answers that.

Comment: *"`W.prototype = window;` is a syntax error,"*. of course it's not, just open console and test it. 20 seconds are enough to confirm that @James Monger's answer is correct while yours is not.