# window as prototype makes setTimeout behave oddly

Tags: javascript

This question is related to my previous question ([using window as a prototype returns seemingly wrong values in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37046063/using-window-as-a-prototype-returns-seemingly-wrong-values-in-javascript/37047024#37047024)) which was answered by @Stubb0rn, but I faced another problem:

```
function W(){
    var w=this;
    Object.defineProperty(this,'window',{configurable:true,enumerable:true,writable:false,value:w});
}
W.prototype=window;
window.setTimeout(function(){console.log("123")});     // works ok
(new W()).setTimeout(function(){console.log("123")});  // throws Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation(…)
```

please note I am using chrome to test

Comment: Why do you keep creating objects which inherit from window?

Comment: WTH are you trying to do? `setTimeout` has to be invoked on a `Window` instance, it just won't work on a `W` object.

Comment: @Bergi I was trying to encapsulate libraries that do not support AMD/requirejs and pollute the global space. I wanted them to have a window object that they can pollute but not effect the real window object and at the same time if they are using window inside their code (like window.setTimeout etc...) I also wanted that to keep working as usual. please see my bellow answer

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it, it turns native functions needs to be called from within window context so I ended binding the functions in window and doing double prototyping like what follows:

```
function define(w){ // for testing I use requirejs define instead
    window.Test123=w;
}
(function(){
    function WBase(){
        for(var i in window){
            if(typeof window[i]=='function'){
                this[i]=window[i].bind(window);
            }
        }
    }
    WBase.prototype=window;
    function W(){
        var w=this;
        Object.defineProperty(this,'window',{configurable:true,enumerable:true,writable:false,value:w});
    }
    W.prototype=new WBase();
    define(function(){
        var windowAlias=new W();
        return (function(window){
            var ret={}; // returns only the variables added to the alias window object
            with(window){

                // CODE FROM MODULE HERE WILL HAVE an alias to "window" wich means if it adds variables to window (global scope) it will be prevented and instead added to the alias window

                for(var i in window){
                    if(window.hasOwnProperty(i)&&i!='window')
                        ret[i]=window[i];
                }
            }
            return ret;
        }).call(windowAlias,windowAlias)
    });
})();

Test123();  // for testing
```

try pasting jquery in place of comment (// CODE FROM MODULE HERE...), you'll get an object with properties jQuery and $ and they will not be added to the global scope. and I ended up creating a page that appends these lines dynamically for javascript files requested through querystring